# Can I rendered javascript object data into c3js chart?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I make a chart by using c3js library. Normally when I click legend, its only shows legend data.

Now, I want to add new `Simple Moving Average` data without remove existing data when I click a legend.

Here is the sample image of what I want,
[image: sample chart]

If I click dept1 legend, I want to add new SMV value to chart.

Here is what I tried,

```
function show_svm(data) {
        chart.load({
            bindto: '#chart',
            x: 'date',
            xFormat: m_d_format,
            json: data,
            keys: {
                x: 'date',
                value:  ['Dept1','Dept2','Dept3', 'Dept4','SMV']
                }
            });
        }
```

In the function argument `data` is like this,

```
{
    'date':["2015-11-23","2015-11-24","2015-11-25","2015-11-26","2015-11-27","2015-11-30","2015-12-01","2015-12-02","2015-12-03","2015-12-04","2015-12-08","2015-12-09","2015-12-11","2015-12-14","2015-12-15","2015-12-16","2015-12-17","2015-12-18","2015-12-19","2015-12-21","2015-12-22","2015-12-23","2015-12-24","2015-12-25","2015-12-28","2015-12-29","2015-12-30","2016-01-04","2016-01-05","2016-01-06","2016-01-07","2016-01-08","2016-01-09","2016-01-11","2016-01-12","2016-01-13","2016-01-14","2016-01-15","2016-01-18","2016-01-19","2016-01-20","2016-01-21","2016-01-22","2016-01-23","2016-01-24","2016-01-25","2016-01-26","2016-01-27","2016-01-28","2016-01-29","2016-02-01","2016-02-02","2016-02-03","2016-02-04","2016-02-05","2016-02-08"],
    'Dept1':["100.00","50.00","57.14","71.43","100.00","42.86","85.71","85.71","71.43","66.67","33.33","100.00","50.00","57.14","66.67","71.43","100.00","57.14","0.00","28.57","57.14","66.67","57.14","57.14","71.43","57.14","57.14","71.43","71.43","71.43","85.71","83.33","100.00","42.86","57.14","57.14","66.67","100.00","71.43","100.00","71.43","14.29","28.57","100.00","50.00","28.57","57.14","57.14","57.14","100.00","42.86","57.14","71.43","71.43","42.86","71.43"],
    'SMV':[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,70.407142857143,73.468571428571,74.83,69.387142857143,69.387142857143,70.407142857143,66.325714285714,63.605714285714,63.605714285714,68.367142857143,71.768571428571,57.482857142857,54.421428571429,54.421428571429,54.421428571429,52.38,46.257142857143,48.298571428571,56.461428571429,60.542857142857,62.584285714286,63.264285714286,65.305714285714,69.387142857143,71.087142857143,77.21,75.17,73.128571428571,71.087142857143,70.407142857143,72.448571428571,70.748571428571,70.748571428571,74.83,68.708571428571,64.627142857143,69.388571428571,62.245714285714,56.122857142857,50,47.958571428571,54.08,64.284285714286,56.121428571429,57.141428571429,63.264285714286,65.305714285714,63.265714285714,65.307142857143]
}
```

This `data` are came from ajax. 
But, this `SVM` data cannot render on chart and I don't get any error. I don't know why.

The another thing I want to know is, can I use javascript object to json of c3js chart like this: `json:data,`. Is it correct way or not?. I'm very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you provide an example in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes. [https://jsfiddle.net/Thura/x3bt84q1/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/Thura/x3bt84q1/1/). But the data are not rendered in chart. I don't know why.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I already create sample in jsfiddle. [https://jsfiddle.net/Thura/x3bt84q1/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/Thura/x3bt84q1/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just a few mistakes in your code. First, you used the attribute `json`. For using that attribute, your data needs to be in the following form:

```
var data = [
    { 'date': '2015-01-01', 'Dept1': null, 'SMV': 3},
    { 'date': '2015-01-02', 'Dept1': 1, 'SMV': 4}
];
```

Your data however looks different. You separated all the `date`, the `Dept1` and the `SMV` data into separate arrays. The way to go here is the following: The data should contain one array of several arrays. The first argument is defined as the key of the dataset. An example dataset looks then like this:

```
var data = [
    ['date', '2015-01-01', 2015-01-02'],
    ['Dept1', null, 1],
    ['SMV', 3, 4]
];
```

You then also do not need the `keys` attribute anymore.

Lastly, you forgot to add the `c3` and `d3` dependencies in your jsFiddle, what led to the error `c3 is not defined`. You can find a fixed example of your jsFiddle here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x3bt84q1/5/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if I want to add another legend while I show smv data for 'dept1'. How can I make it?

Comment: Please help me. How can I add another legend into this chart. Is it possible?

Comment: With legend, you mean another dataset? Something like "Dept2"? And when do you want the data to be there? Initially, or after some time, initiated by an event (or timeout)?

Comment: Yes, Its pretty the same as you said.

Comment: Just add another array to the array of data, if you want to have more data. And if you want to add it later on, you can call the following command: `chart.load({'columns': [ ['new_dataset', 2, 4] ] });` where chart is the object you get in return of `c3.generate()`.